# Differences and relation between retrospective power analysis and a posteriori power analysis?

Tags: statistical-power

From [a note](http://core.ecu.edu/psyc/wuenschk/stathelp/PowerAnalysis_Overview.doc)

> **A Priori Power Analysis.**  This is an important part of planning research.  You determine how many cases you will need to have a good chance of detecting an effect of a specified size with the desired amount of power.  See my document Estimating the Sample Size Necessary to Have Enough Power for required number of cases to have 80% for common designs.
>
> **A Posteriori Power Analysis.** Also know as “post hoc” power analysis.  Here you find how much power you would have if you had a specified number of cases.  Is it “a posteriori” only in the sense that you provide the number of number of cases, as if you had already conducted the research. Like “a priori” power analysis, it is best used in the planning of research – for example, I am planning on obtaining data on 100 cases, and I want to know whether or not would give me adequate power.
>
> **Retrospective Power Analysis.**  Also known as “observed power.”  There are several types, but basically this involves answering the following question:  “If I were to repeat this research, using the same methods and the same number of cases, and if the size of the effect in the population was exactly the same as it was in the present sample, what would be the probability that I would obtain significant results?”  Many have demonstrated that this question is foolish, that the answer tells us nothing of value, and that it has led to much mischief.  See this discussion from Edstat-L.  I also recommend that you read Hoenig and Heisey (The American Statistician, 2001, 55, 19-24).  A few key points:
>
> - Some stat packs (SPSS) give you “observed power” even though it is useless.
> - “Observed power” is perfectly correlated with the value of p – that is, it provides absolutely no new information that you did not already have.
> - It is useless to conduct a power analysis AFTER the research has been completed.  What you should be doing is calculating confidence intervals for effect sizes.

I was confused what differences and relation are between Retrospective Power Analysis and A Posteriori power analysis?  I think they both have a given sample size and try to estimate the power?

What does "the size of the effect in the population was exactly the same as it was in the present sample" mean?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assume for simplicity that your model is defined by only one parameter $\theta$. The power is the function $\theta \mapsto \Pr(\text{reject } H_0 \mid \theta)$, which depends on the sample size $n$.

In **Retrospective Power Analysis**, you only plug in your estimate $\theta$: you look at the value $\Pr(\text{reject } H_0 \mid \hat\theta)$ at the power function at $\theta=\hat\theta$, with the same sample size $n$. It answers the question: *"what would be the probability that I would obtain significant results if $\theta$ were $\hat\theta$"* ? As said in your text this question is rather useless because there is a one-to-one correspondence between the $p$-value and the retrospective power $\Pr(\text{reject } H_0 \mid \hat\theta)$.
For instance consider a binomial experiment with proportion parameter $\theta \in [0,1]$ and the hypothesis $H_0\colon\{\theta=0\}$. Obviously the power increases when $\theta$ increases. And obviously the $p$-value decreases when $\hat\theta$ increases. Consequently the lower $p$-value, the higher RP (retrospective power). A couple of years ago I wrote a R code for the case of Fisher tests in classical Gaussian linear models. [It is here.](http://forums.cirad.fr/logiciel-R/viewtopic.php?t=2452) There's a code using simulations for the one-way ANOVA example and a code for the general model providing an exact calculation of RP in function of the $p$-value and the design parameters. I called my function `PAP()` because "Puissance a posteriori" is the French translation of RP and PAP is also an acronym for "Power Approach Paradox". The cause of the decreasing correspondence between $p$ and RP for Gaussian linear models is intuitively the same as for the binomial experiment: if $\theta$ is "far from $H_0$" then the power at $\theta$ is high, and if $\hat\theta$ is "far from $H_0$" then the $p$-value is small. Theoretically this is a consequence of the fact that the noncentral Fisher distributions are stochastically increasing in the noncentrality parameter (see [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58107/conditional-expectation-of-r-squared) about noncentral $F$ distributions in Gaussian linear models). In fact here the noncentrality parameter plays the role of $\theta$ (is it the so-called *effect size* ? I don't know).
I claimed "RS is rather useless because of the correspondence with $p$" because this decreasing correspondence with $p$ means that *having a high RP is equivalent to having a small $p$, and vice-versa*. But the more serious problem is the misinterpretation of RP;  for instance, I have found such claims in the literature:

- $H_0$ is not rejected and RP is high, so the decision of the test is significant.
- $H_0$ is not rejected, it is not surprising because RP is low.
- $H_0$ is rejected (so the decision is significant) and RP is high, so the decision is even more significant.

Respectively replace "RP is high" and "RP is low" with "$p$ is low" and "$p$ is high" in the three claims above and you will see that they are either useless, wrong, or puzzling.
From a more "philosophical" perspective, RP is useless because why would we mind about the probability that rejection of $H_0$ occurs once the experiment is done ?
See also here a funny but clever [retrospective power online calculator](https://web.archive.org/web/20140625063226/http://www.onetrickwords.com/retro.htm) ;-)

The paragraph **A Posteriori Power Analysis** says nothing about the choice of $\theta$, but it emphasizes the main difference with the retrospective power: here the goal is to use the information issued from your first experiment to evaluate the power of a future experiment, focusing on the sample size. A sensible approach to evaluate this power is to consider your estimate $\hat\theta$ as a "guess" of the true $\theta$ and also to *consider the uncertainty about this estimate*. There is a natural way to do so in Bayesian statistics, namely the *predictive power*, which consists to average the possible values of $\Pr(\text{reject } H_0 \mid \theta)$ for various values of $\theta$, according to some distribution (the posterior distribution in Bayesian terms) representing the knowledge and the uncertainty about $\theta$ resulting from your first experiment. In the frequentist framework you could consider the values of the power evaluated at the bounds of your confidence interval about $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks! I don't quite understand the added example. Why is the retrospective power analysis  is rather useless because there is a one-to-one correspondance between the p-value and the restrospective power?

Comment: Thanks! (1) In Retrospective Power Analysis, how is the estimate $\hat{\theta}$ of $θ$ estimated from a sample? (2) I asked a question to understand the relation between observed power and p-value, after looking up in the paper "Abuse of Power" by Hoenig and Heisey here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59409/relation-between-observed-power-and-p-value

Comment: Added to (1) is a retrospective power a function of the sample $X$ through the estimate $\hat{\theta}$, while what a posteriori power analysis get is the power function, not depending on the sample $X$?

Comment: @Tim 1) Users take the classical estimate (maximum likelihood, unbiaised, least-squares, ...), nothing particular in the context of RP. 2) Nice idea to open a new discussion; but too late for me to answer tonight. See you.

Comment: (1) In A Posteriori Power Analysis, is it okay to just evaluate the power at each alternative sample distribution, instead of summarizing the powers over all alternative sample distributions, using either Bayes or frequentist idea as in your last paragraph? (2) In A Posteriori Power Analysis, the result isn't a function of the sample in either Bayes or Frequentist summary, while retrospective power is a function of the sample?

Comment: (3) In retrospective power, is either the estimate of the parameter or the true parameter of the sample, or both, assumed to be from alternative, so that it is a "power" instead of a FP rate?

Comment: (1) In this case you don't use the information from your 1st experiment, so you're just doing power analysis. Before the 1st experiment, you have no information about the unknown parameters. After the 1st experiment you have some, for instance a range of likely values (a confidence interval), and in APPA (A Posterior Power Analysis), you use this information to have a more precise idea of the power. (2) The main goal of APPA is to chose a sample size sufficiently large in order to have a sufficiently high power to reject $H_0$ (for instance in order to have $80\%$ probability to reject $H_0$)

Comment: (3) Why do you care about such details ? It is not important to define the power function only on $H_1$. "Power" is a shortcut for "probability to reject $H_0$".

Comment: Thanks! About (3), I was trying to understand whether the higher the retrospective power is, the better or worse it is. If the sample distribution or its estimate is in null, the higher the worse, and if it is in alternative, the higher the better. isn't it?

Comment: @Tim You should stop now to search such ideas - there's only one  thing to know: high retrospective power $\iff$ small $p$-value.

Comment: Hi Stéphane, is it correct that a posterior power analysis and a Priori Power Analysis are both not depending on the data, and therefore are priori analysis? On the other hand, retrospective power analysis depends on data, and is therefore post hoc analysis?

Comment: @Tim With posterior power analysis, you use the information brought by the data of a first experiment to assess the power of a future experiment.

Answer (score 5):

When you do an a posteriori power analysis you have to plug in an effect size and a variance. If you plug in the *observed* effect size and variance, as you do in an a posteriori power analysis, you are assuming that the true effect size is the same as the observed.

Comment: Thanks! What does "variance" mean, in "When you do an a posteriori power analysis you have to plug in an effect size and a variance"?

Comment: Also what is "effect size" in a testing? Is it the test statistic and/or its observation?

Comment: @Tim Variance is the standard deviation squared. The reasons for using variance in place of standard deviation usually don't matter, but it is 'unbiassed' whereas the standard deviation isn't. (If you haven't heard of variance or effect size, you might be well served by starting with them instead of power analyses.)

Comment: @MichaelLew I don't know what is effect size as well (sometimes $\mu/\sigma$ is called effect size but I don't know the general definition).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I don't believe that you can write the answer that you did above without knowing what effect size means. Try this question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18028/desired-effect-size-vs-expected-effect-size or wikipedia.

Comment: @MichaelLew ?? Don't need a special terminology to calculate a probability...

Comment: @MichaelLew I have taken a look at your link: the word "effect size" is used many times, but never defined.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent The difference between the null hypothesis and the  true parameter is the effect size. It is necessary to specify an effect size in order to calculate power.

Comment: @MichaelLew http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59559/is-there-a-general-definition-of-the-effect-size