# How can I interpret this correlation?

Tags: r, correlation, p-value, regression-coefficients

I got correlation coefficient r = 0.33
but my p-value = 0.124 > 0.05
Is there a non-significant correlation or no correlation at all?

Comment: Please read some of the many threads on the topic how to interpret (insignificant) p-values. For example: [How do you know if an insignificant P value is because of chance error or because the sample size of the data is too small?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/578478/237901)

Answer (score 0):

> I got correlation coefficient r = 0.0001 but my p-value = 0.000001 <
> 0.05. I have a massive dataset. Is there a non-significant correlation or no correlation at all?

> I flipped a penny one and a dime once and they both landed on heads. I
> got correlation coefficient r = 1 but my p-value is more than 0.05.

The "technically correct" answer to your question may or may not be what you want. However, it is this:

> I got correlation coefficient r = 0.33 but my p-value = 0.124 > 0.05
> Is there a non-significant correlation or no correlation at all?

There is a non-significant correlation (the same as in the second example).