# Simulate data for power analysis of logistic regression model - include covariance variance of variables?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, simulation, statistical-power

I've tried to simulate data for a power analysis of a logistic regression. The results of the power analysis look reasonable: power=90% for a sample of 6000 persons. But I feel that the analysis lacks something. So, my question is: when generating the data should I include something about how the variables are correlated, or their covariance, other than just defining their linear relationship as I have done in the example below, and if so where do I write that into the code?

I know other questions look like this but I'm not confident that they answer this question.

```
library(plyr) # functions
## Define Function
simfunktion <- function() {
   # Number in each sample
  antal <- 6000
  beta0 <- log(0.16) # logit in reference group
  beta1 <- log(1.1)  # logit given smoking
  beta2 <- log(1.1)  # logit given SNP(genevariation)
  beta3 <- log(1.2)  # logit for interactioncoefficient for SNP*rygning
   ## Smoking variable, with probabilities defined according to empirical studies.
  smoking  <- sample(x = 0:2, size = antal, replace = TRUE, prob = c(40,25,40))
   ## SNP variables with probabilities defined according to empirical studies
  SNP      <- sample(x = 0:2, size = antal, replace = TRUE, prob = c(40,40,20))
   ## calculated probabilites given the model:
  pi.x     <- exp( beta0 + beta1*smoking + beta2*SNP + beta3*smoking*SNP) / 
              ( 1 + exp(beta0 + beta1*smoking + beta2*SNP + beta3*smoking*SNP) )
   ## binoial events given the probabilities:
  sim.y    <- rbinom( n = antal, size = 1, prob = pi.x)  
  sim.data <- data.frame(sim.y, smoking, SNP)
   #################### p-value of the interaction is extracted:
   ## the model is run:
  glm1     <- glm( data = sim.data, formula = sim.y ~ smoking + SNP + smoking:SNP, 
                  family=binomial )
   ## p-value of the interactionterm is extracted:
  summary(    glm( data = sim.data, formula = sim.y ~ smoking + SNP + smoking:SNP, 
                  family=binomial ))$coef[4,4]
}
pvalue     <- as.vector(replicate( 100 , simfunktion()))
mean(pvalue < 0.05)
```

Comment: Readers here may be interested in the following general overview of topics related to power analyses via simulation: [Simulation of logistic regression power analysis: designed experiments](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35940/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Let me throw out some thoughts, and we'll see if something helps you.*

**Some preliminaries:**

- I find it a bit odd that you are defining your true betas as the log of some number; is that because you are using reported odds ratios?  (If so, this is perfectly appropriate.)
- It's important to realize when doing power analyses based on effects reported in the literature that the results are optimistic.  I discuss that here: [Desired effect size vs. expected effect size](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18028//18172#18172); you may also want to read this thread: [Logistic regression model manipulation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60109/).
- I notice that you are simulating the expected distribution of your covariates.  That's not typically done; in general, we assume that our covariates are a set of known constants.  However, if you will be doing observational (e.g., epidemiological) research, these can well vary and this strategy is appropriate.
- Your covariates have the values `0, 1, 2`.  Are these levels of a factor, or are they equal interval?  I ask because they look like the former, but are treated as the latter in the data generating process.

**Your main question:**

- If your covariates will be correlated with each other, your power will decrease, so **yes**, you should definitely try to incorporate that information into the simulation.
- You want to do that where you are generating the distribution of your covariates.
- Generating correlated data is slightly more complicated.  There is a general thread on this topic on CV here: [How to generate correlated random numbers (given means, variances, and degree of correlation)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38856/).
- Your situation is potentially even a little more complicated still, because your values are only `0, 1, 2`.  This can be done using [copulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28probability_theory%29) (search the site, I think there are some informative threads somewhere).  Alternatively, you could list the probabilities of the nine possible combinations, use `sample()` (similarly to what you have already), and then assign the associated values.

Comment: Excellent info and links, enough to get me going. And yes you are right this is for epidemiological studies :)